# Run JS Code on userlog out

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to delete a variable stored in local storage when user logs out of WordPress, none of the two code blocks below work for me, both have been tested in my functions.php file one at a time.

```
  function del_local_reload_var() {
        $str = <<<HD

      <script> 
      localStorage.removeItem("justOnce");
      </script>
    HD;
    echo $str;
    }
    add_action('wp_logout', 'del_local_reload_var');
```

Second method:

```
    function del_local_reload_var() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'localStorage.removeItem( "justOnce" )';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    add_action('wp_logout', 'del_local_reload_var');
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? I think it is possible that you are using `localStorage` in a wrong way (your question suggests that you are using it to store private data).

Comment: no im not, it's just storing a value key

Comment: Of course you are storing a value key, but is it private? Does it belongs only to current logged in user? Maybe you need `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`? Anyway, see @MarkKaplun's answers, I think he is right.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_logout` is being triggered server side when the user is logging out, but the fact that it is being triggered do not indicate that there is a browser on the other side that actually triggered it. For example a user might log out via Ajax and then the JS code will not be evaluated.

In any case, it is much better to define a logged out user as one that do not have the authentication cookie. You can do something like

```
if (value in local storage) {
  if (wordpress cookie exists)
    remove value from local storage
}
```

Anyway, if you want to be able to control client data from the server you should use cookies instead of local storage.

Comment: Also, if the logout is performed through [logout url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url), a HTTP redirection occurs right after `wp_logout()` is executed, so, the JavaScript in `wp_logout` action is never sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since WordPress redirects you to the login page, add the JavaScript to a code block on there. Something like:

```
function my_remove_local_storage() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['loggedout'] ) && $_GET['loggedout'] == 'true' ) { ?>
        <script>localStorage.removeItem("justOnce");</script>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'login_form', 'my_remove_local_storage' );
```